# Changing Character Width from Current Size to Zero using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a character that I want to shrink (in this case horizontally) to zero when its clicked.

If, however, I start with   `from { width: 1em; }` in my `keyframes` animation, it doesnt start with the characters individual width but the general font size, which may be wider, and will therefore cause all text to shift to the opposite direction at first.

How can I assign the starting width to be the actual width of the character?

```js
const app = document.getElementById("clickMe");
app.innerHTML =
  "Click Me"
    .split("")
    .map(function (char) {
      return (
        '<span class="character" onclick="clickEvent(this)">' +
        char +
        "</span>"
      );
    })
    .join("")

function clickEvent(char) {
    char.classList.add("character-clicked");
}
```

```css
.character {
  font-size: xx-large;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.character-clicked {
  animation-name: shrink;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes shrink {
  from {
    width: 1em;
  }
  to {
    width: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="clickMe"/>
```

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use max-width instead and make sure you consider a value bigger than the font. Your `1em` will do the job here

```js
const app = document.getElementById("clickMe");
app.innerHTML =
  "Click Me"
    .split("")
    .map(function (char) {
      return (
        '<span class="character" onclick="clickEvent(this)">' +
        char +
        "</span>"
      );
    })
    .join("")

function clickEvent(char) {
    char.classList.add("character-clicked");
}
```

```css
.character {
  font-size: xx-large;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.character-clicked {
  animation-name: shrink;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes shrink {
  from {
    max-width: 1em;
  }
  to {
    max-width: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="clickMe"/>
```